# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with ngClass and no child component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-changedetection

I am trying to apply active class to my route using a custom logic, `routerLinkActive` is not working for some reason (may be my parent and child routes are dynamic). Here's the code:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item eds-service"
     *ngFor="let service of services"
     [routerLink]="['', _dataService.flavor, service]"
     [ngClass]="{'active': _urlService.getCurrentService() === service}"
     (click)="changeService(service)">
     {{ service | readableName | titlecase }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

My routing file looks like this:

```
{ path: ':flavor', component: ComparePageComponent },
{ path: ':flavor/:service', component: ComparePageComponent }
```

When I load the page, I get the following error:

> ServicesComponent.html:10 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'active: false'. Current value:
>   'active: true'.

I tried to use the `AfterViewInit`, `AfterViewChecked`, but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't call external services like `_urlService.getCurrentService()` directly from the template, because the value can change after the template is checked. Therefore you get this error.

Comment: @cgTag, what would be the best way to do it?? Even if I create a getter method in the .ts class that gets _urlService.getCurrentService() value and then use the getter method on the template I get the same error.

Comment: For more information about Angular's infamous "expression changed" error: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: it will be great to create a sample for us. And for the code, do you have the default active: true for one of the link?

Comment: ftr: I have exactly the same problem, coming from ngClass: "Previous value: 'stepper-label-active: true'. Current value: 'stepper-label-active: false'". My isActive() method is directly in the component of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

See here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4